# Use timer in a UIImageView Subclass

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, subclass

I want to change the picture of my custom UIImageView Subclass by a timer. But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

This is my code:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        [self update];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)update {

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(change) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)change {

    self.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: its a small mistake please check my ans ..

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use `image` property also to assign any image to imageView small rectification see below code.

Also do not give variable name same as its class property.

```
-(void)update {

    self.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Green.png"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(change) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)change {
    self.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Red.png"];
}
```

> self.image.**image** peoperty added here

Edit:

change your property from `UIImage` to `UIImageView` like see below

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;`

---

.h Header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface orientation : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
@end
```

---

.m Message file

```
#import "orientation.h"

@interface orientation ()

@end

@implementation orientation

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self update];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)update {

    self.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"investment1.png"];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(change) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)change {
    self.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logout.png"];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I add the property?

Comment: just write .image in front of self.image in your code ..or use mine

Comment: see my updated ans .. property should be `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;`

Comment: change your property with `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;`

Comment: I did. But it doesn't work. Do you have a image or image view subclass in mind?

Comment: code working fine i have tested after :) .. yes i am using imageview

Comment: Can you send me .h and .m please? :)

Comment: Thanks. Can you add the code of the custom class, too please?

Comment: thats only code i have used just apply yourself John ..please vote up or accept my ans :)

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The question is about a subclass of `UIImageView` and getting that code work. Why offer a solution that ignores the original code and creates a whole new view controller?